How to fill Excel formula up dynamically, in upper direction?
I am trying to fill out a formula up dynamically. I mean, without specifying the exact range.
I know where I am located in the Excel. That means, we can use ActiveCell. I just filled out the ActiveCell (AD24) with the formula (See screenshot below for more details). Now I want it to be dragged up to AD12. But without explicitally specifying AD12, because the file is evolving and it could be longer in the future. Here is the code I am using now. But it has AD12 and AD24, which are fix values and not dynamic.
Is there a way to just fill out the formula up to whatever row (upper direction) is filled out in the column just to the left of the cell where I am located?
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-3]-1,""-"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("AD12:AD24"), Type:=xlFillDefault



I'm not sure i I understood properly but looks like you got a column with dynamic quantity of rows and you want to fill an adjacent column with a formula, based of that quantity of rows.
In this example, I want to apply a formula in the yellow column to all rows based on the left column:

You need to know at least one starting cell. In this case, I know my data will start always at cell C6. I don't know how many rows but the code will handle it:
Sub test()
Dim LR As Long
Dim StartingCell As Range
Dim MyFormula As String

Set StartingCell = Range("C6")

LR = StartingCell.End(xlDown).Row

'fill column to the right with formula
MyFormula = "=RC[-1]*100"

With StartingCell
    Range(.Offset(0, 1), .Offset(LR - .Row, 1)).FormulaR1C1 = MyFormula
End With

Set StartingCell = Nothing

End Sub

After executing code I get this:

The code will work even if the amount of rows is dynamic but must be consecutive (no blanks). If you got blanks you need a different approach.


Are you looking for code that will work regardless of what the active cell is - and will just 'fill-up' from that cell based on the cells to it's left? If so, this should work:
With ActiveCell
    numofrows = .Row - .Offset(, -1).End(xlUp).Row - 1
    .Offset(-numofrows).Resize(numofrows + 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(RC[-2]/RC[-3]-1,""-"")"
End With

Note: this is tweaked based on the top row including a header.

Excel's built-in calculation order is top to bottom, left to right. Yes, Excel can calculate any cell from any position, but the design works from top left to bottom right, and that design is supportet with the built-in tools.
Filling up is not in the toolkit. Filling down is easy with a double click on the fill handle.
Typically, new data is entered at the bottom of a table, not at the top.
If you stick with these principles, there will be no need to extend a formula towards the top of the sheet.
My advice is to work with Excel in the way it is intended, instead of working against its calculation flow.

I can be (dynamically with offsetting / find) in AD12, and want to fill the formula down to AD24. How to do that dynamically, if AC12 to AC24 are already filled out? But assume I don't know in which cell I am, but the cursor is on AD12. What would be the code for it, to fill the formula in the question down?

This code generate the below result:
Active cell is the cell with the formula. This can be set either manually or at the beginning of the code. When the code works the active cell must be the cell with the formula.
It checks the top row of the column to the left with contiguous data in it.
Generate the range as text from the active cell address and the top row of the data,
and then with FillUp copy the formula.
Sub formulaup()

toprow = ActiveCell.Offset(0, -1).End(xlUp).Row
acadd = ActiveCell.Address
rownum = Mid(acadd, InStr(InStr(1, acadd, "$") + 1, acadd, "$") + 1)
newadd = Replace(acadd, rownum, toprow) & ":" & acadd
Range(newadd).FillUp

End Sub

The original content

After the run of the code

